# Validating inputs that have the same name attribute

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I have a form that allows a user to add as many people to their account that they would like. Here is a small sample of my form:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name[]" required>
<input type="text" name="last_name[]" required>
```

The problem I am having is validating the form. The first instance of `first_name[]` and `last_name[]` will validate. However, any additional instances will not. I have done some research and this is due to the inputs having the same name attribute. I have tried adding a unique ID to each dynamically added input but that did not work.

Also, I have tried the jQuery validate plugin with no luck either.

Comment: If im correct you are trying to make a form that allows the user to enter a list of names. And then that list of names (inputs) needs to be submitted. A better UI design would be a form that accepts one user at a time, or if you have to do it this way dynamically add the inputs using first_name_1, first_name_2, first_name_3 without seeing the full UI of your design it's hard to advise. Can you post more code

Comment: I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tq7phnkb/) and it seems to work just fine. All the inputs are required

Comment: @MartinWebb, the reason I am using the form such as this `first_name[]` is because the form will be submitted and processed using PHP. The naming format is required to loop through the submitted form.

Comment: @RicardoRibeiro, hmmm, that is odd because that same setup is not working for me. The fiddle works but on my website it does not. I am going to try to disable the jquery validate plugin to see what happens.

Comment: Please add the code that does the validation, I'm pretty sure you are querying the DOM in a way that only finds the first control with the name... you should get the collection of elements in the form with the name or of `type="text"`. Check how you loop troughs them.

Comment: The issue won't be php side its that your validate function can't validate the names with the first_name[] structure. Either use a index system as i proposed or turn a simple validate that checks the inputs directly by class or by id, or by circling the form.

Comment: I guess you missed [this part of the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations):  *"A **'name' attribute must also be unique** to the form, as this is how the plugin keeps track of all input elements."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the jquery validate plugin. Once I removed this, the HTML5 required attributes worked like expected.

Comment: I assumed you were using code to validate... greate solution.